# App reloads when iframe response is 302

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I have an SPA written in angular. The app sends a request to server in a hidden iframe requesting an access token. The server returns the token in the url as part of fragment (the reply url is configured at server already, it knows where to send the response). The response is a 302. The url looks like http://example.com/#token=dsdcsvfv&state=43242...

When the response comes back, the entire app is reloaded (app.js code is executed again) in the iframe. This happens even before the locationChangeHandler runs. I am only interested in fetching the token from the url (which happens in locationChangeHandler), I don't intend to load anything in the iframe, its hidden anyways. Is there a way to prevent this reload?

I am not sure if we can prevent the redirect that the server sent to the iframe, cause that is what is causing the reload IMO.

Comment: Why the hidden frame? Can't you do this via $http GET ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the frame...try adding a sandbox to your iframe like so: `<iframe sandbox>` it should not allow the parent to be redirected.
Here's more about it : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp